# Is it possible in PHP to change the value of an array permanently?

Tags: php

```
static $l1 = array(1,"_" , "_", "_");
static $l2 = array("_", 2, "_", "_");
static $l3 = array("_", "_", 2, "_");
static $l4 = array("_", "_", "_", "_");

static $c1 = array(1, 4, 3, 2);
static $c2 = array(3, 2, 4, 1);
static $c3 = array(4, 1, 2, 3);
static $c4 = array(2, 3, 1, 4);
```

I am basically trying to make a 2x2 sudoku Game. I have one list of arrays from l1 and l4 which is for guessing and another set c1 to c4 as the answer. User will input the value, row number and column number and if the all the parameters are correct (after comparing with the answer set, c1 to c4), it should change the value in either l1, l2, l3 or l4 depending on the input. The problem is that PHP doesn't stores array information like that, is there a way out? I want to make this program as simple as possible.

```
if ($_POST['n2'] == 1) {
    if ($_POST['n1'] == $c1[$_POST['n3']-1]) {
        $l1[$_POST['n3']-1] = $_POST['n1'];
    } else {
        echo "Try again";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should to go read up on sessions.

Comment: @CBroe I can do it with sessions, is there any other way ? Like an easy way which my trainees could understand because sessions is not covered yet.

Comment: @dlporter98, this is a program for my trainees, and multidimensional arrays have not been covered yet.

Comment: You basically need some form of persistent storage such as PHP sessions, browser cookies, backend db, or backend static files.

Answer (score 0):

You could either save player's actions in a session or database. It depends on what you want. 
Requesting the way you are trying won't make it dynamic.

Take a look at
[PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) and [PHP MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use some sort of persistence storage, you will need to keep track of all the data in each request. This means sending the solution so far as well as the final solution to the browser and back to the script each time.

using POST

```
<?php
$rowNumber = $_POST['rowNubmer'];
$columnNumber = $_POST['columnNumer'];
$guessedValue = $_POST['guessedValue'];
$codedSolutionSoFar = $_POST['solutionSoFar'];
$solutionSoFar = myDecodeFunction($codedSolitionSoFar);

$codedFinalSolution = $_POST['finalSolution'];
$finalSolution = myDecodeFunction($codedSolitionSoFar);

function myDecodeFunction($codedString) {
  $decoded = explode(',', $codedString);
  return $decoded;
}

function myEncodeFunction(array $sudokuGameValues) {
  $encoded = implode(',', $sodukoGameValues);
  return $encoded;
}

function checkGuessedValue($row, $column, $value, $solution) {
  // this is hardcoded for a 2x2 sudoku where the values are stored in
  // a flat array as [(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)]
  $indexInSolition = $row * 2 + $column;
  $correctValue = $solution[$indexInSolution];
  return $value === $correctValue;
}
...
sprintf(
   '<input type="hidden" name="finalSolution" value="%s">',
    myEncodeFunction($finalSolution)
);
sprintf(
   '<input type="hidden" name="solitionSoFar" value="%s">',
    myEncodeFunction($solutionSoFar)
);
```

Please note that the above is not complete, complete and utterly ignores input filtering, is bad practice and serves solemnly as a solution to build upon. But since it is for a class it might be usable. From there you can explain all the mistakes and problems that come with code like this. But everyone will love the idea of being able to look up the solution in the HTML source code and this gives the argument you need to introduce server side storage e.g. as already suggested in a session.